# Restart an app on button click

Tags: iphone, xcode

Can i restart an app on button click.Is it possible to call viewDidLoad method after app loading completed?.

Comment: i dont think so.. you can kill the app.. and take the user to the Home screen. After that user has to click on your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate a restart by tearing down your view controller and reinitializing it. I.e. in your `appDelegates` `didFinishLaunching` method, send a message to itself like `[self setupApp]`
and in that `setupApp` method, create your `rootViewController` etc..

Then when you want to simulate a restart, tear down everything and call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] ]setupApp]`

Comment: quote :you can maybe just fake a stop/start if that's what you need... but it won't help you with a memory issue"

Comment: Why the downvote? OP never mentioned anything about having memory issues.

Comment: because it is what I said way earlier and it didn't help him at all apparently, anyways Ill revoke my vote... it goes more against the op

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using a Jailbroken device, it is almost impossible that apple will allow you to do same.

Apple will reject your app.

One thing you can do is, show an alert message "Please quit and restart".

Comment: exit or crash :D they won't reject for crashing, id guess

Comment: @Daij-Djan : i didn't get you ? :(

Comment: while app loading i have a login screen which allow user to enter to home screen.there logout option which comes out from home screen.i can not get back my login screen.

Comment: again load that login screen.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

Only you can close your app by "exit(0);".

You can't restart it.

Answer (score 0):

impossible but you either can just quit.. e.g. using `exit(-1)` or so

OR

you can maybe just fake a stop/start if that's what you need... but it won't help you with a memory issue